# How we can parse AAMVA parse data in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

I have data like

```
"DCBADCDNONEDBA10182022DCSNAMEDACNAME2DDADNAME3DBD12282017".
```

It is an **AAMVA** parser data. How I can split this data in Javascript?

Comment: split like what ? Do you wants to split in to single

Comment: I want to split it separately like this : DCBA
DCDNONE
DBA10182022
DCSNAME
DACNAME2
DDADNAME3
DBD12282017

Comment: so it there is any patter, If there is I can provide an answer

Comment: No pattern, But I want data like "DCBA DCDNONE DBA10182022 DCSNAME DACNAME2 DDADNAME3 DBD12282017" and split it with "\n"

Comment: Is this do what you wants `var str = "DCBADCDNONEDBA10182022DCSNAMEDACNAME2DDADNAME3DBD12282017";
  var res = str.split("");console.log(res)`

Comment: yes, I want to split this but it doesn't have any space or common thing to split it...

Comment: Yep test the code youll see the output.

Comment: Please let me know if you need anyother help

Comment: I want like this :DCBA
DCDNONE
DBA10182022
DCSNAME
DACNAME2
DADNAME3
DBD12282017

Comment: To do something like that you should have a patter

Comment: Ok, then I will try to have some pattern.

Comment: sure let us know if you want any help

Comment: Ya sure... Thanks